# What links these numbers?

Tags: knowledge, geography, history

What links the following numbers (and many more) in the UK:

```
150 -> 1101
1262 -> 1261
241 -> 284 (B)
2035 -> [2,Unclassified] -> [460 (C), 2003 (B)]
398 -> 361 -> 3277 (B)
3001 -> 455 (B)
434 -> [4014 (B), 419] -> [4014 (B), 4008 (B)]
4073 -> 470
568 -> 5419 (B)
5041 -> Unclassified
622 -> [6001 (B), 625] 
622 (temporary) -> 56
6134 -> 61
715 -> 7084 (B)
7002 -> 801
840 -> 874 (B)
8006 -> 806
927 -> [952 (B), 954 (B)]
```

I can add some American equivalents if people are struggling here

Comment: They're all rot13(cbfvgvir vagrtref).

Comment: rot13(ubj qb v qbjaibgr n pbzzrag?)

Comment: Does order matter?

Comment: @simonalexander2005 I think it has many answers. It would be better if you would edit this question a bit so that you may get the intended answer.

Comment: Any better? I've tried to add some more information

Comment: I'm British and I know what these are. I'll let others try first.

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica As am I, but I haven't got the foggiest! Maybe you should post - you seem to know the answer...

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica Actually, now I do - but you were here first, go for it :) (Unless TruVortex_07 can develop their answer further, I guess!)

Comment: @Bewilderer no, the rows are just sorted numerically (sort of...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @TruVortex_07 identified for line one, these are all

> Road numbers in Great Britain

The first column represents

> Original road names

And the second column (after the `->`) represents

> Current road names

For example

> According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A1101_road), road A1101 was previously known as A150. Going down the list, we see that each road number in the first column is no longer in use. For example, road A1262 is now A1261 ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_roads_in_Zone_1_of_the_Great_Britain_numbering_scheme)), road A241 is now B284 ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_roads_in_Zone_2_of_the_Great_Britain_numbering_scheme)), etc.

Comment: i was just going to edit my post but you beat me to it ;)

Comment: @TruVortex_07 you had it first. You can edit yours and OP accept your answer!

Comment: naw, your answer is much more complete and expanded on

Answer (score 1):

I might have an answer for the first line:

> A150 road -> A1101 Road as A150 turned into part of A1101

As for the full explanation, see Daniel C's answer!

Comment: You're on the right lines - but what do I mean by "->"? Why those in particular? The relationship between the two then applies to the rest as well - they're all examples of the same thing.